# Method in vuex action return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have the following method in my Vuex action:

```js
const actions = {
  async fetchByQuery({ commit, title }) {
    console.log(title);
    //other codes
  },
};
```

And method to reach to vuex action:

```js
  methods: {
     ...mapActions(["fetchByQuery"]),
    getData(title) {
        console.log("teacher");
      this.fetchByQuery(title);
    }
  }
```

But the console.log() from action is giving `undefined` output in the console.

What am I missing here ??

Answer (score 1):

You got the parameters inside your action wrong.

`({ commit, title })` has to be `({ commit }, title)`

Otherwise you would have to call it with an object with a property title.

Answer (score 0):

Vuex actions expect two parameters, the context object `{ commit }` and the payload (`title`, in your case)

Change your action declaration to this:

```
const actions = {
  async fetchByQuery({ commit }, title) {
    console.log(title);
    //other codes
  },
};
```